# With how many ways can we arrange the numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

With how many ways can we arrange the numbers $1, 2, \dots, 15$ so that at each position that is a multiple of $3$, there is an even number.

My idea is the following:
$$ \frac{10!}{7! \cdot 2!}$$

Could you tell me if this is correct??

Comment: How did you arrive at that? I get $\displaystyle \binom{7}{5}.5!10! = \frac{7!10!}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 positions that must each have one of the 7 even numbers, how many ways are there to put 5 of the 7 even numbers into those positions? How many ways can the remaining 10 numbers be put into the remaining 10 positions? Clearly following this 2-step procedure will always result in a valid solution for the original problem. You also need to check that no two ways of following the procedure gives the same solution. That will prove that counting according to the procedure gives the correct answer, because every solution is counted exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 positions corresponding to multiples of 3, and 7 even numbers to choose from. So first choose 7 out of 5, then permutate the 5 chosen even numbers, then finally the remaining 10 numbers, giving $\displaystyle \binom{7}{5}.5!10! = \frac{7!10!}{2}$